# Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase keeps asking me to run LoginAzureRmAccount

Tags: azure-powershell

I have an Azure SQL database which I want to delete. The command should be:

```
Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $dbResourceGroup -ServerName $dbServerName -DatabaseName $dbToDelete -Whatif -Force
```

The error I keep getting back is

```
Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
```

I tried running **`Login-AzureRmAccount`** as myself, then as a service principal I use for unattended scripts, and nothing worked.

I am able to log into the Azure RM portal and delete databases. I am also able to run **`Invoke-SqlCmd`** against this database to query and manipulate data.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Powershell Azure modules had dependency errors for something. To fix it I (at the behest of Microsoft tech support) ran:

```
PS C:\> Install-Module AzureRM -Force
```

This re-installed it and fixed the dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

According to this error message, it seems that you have not login Azure whit the right subscription.

We can use this command to get the sql database's information, and check the subscription.

`(Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName jasontest1 -ServerName jasontest -ResourceGroupName jasontest).resourceid`

Then we can find the subscription in the powershell output.

```
PS C:\Users> (Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName jasontest1 -ServerName jasontest -ResourceGroupName jasontest).resourceid
/subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx/resourceGroups/jasontest/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/jasontest/databases/jasontest1
```

To find which subscription, we can use this command `Get-AzureRmSubscription` to list it:

```
PS C:\Users> Get-AzureRmSubscription


Name     : Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN
Id       : 5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx
TenantId : 1fcfxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx9-xxxx8bf8xxxx
State    : Enabled
```

Also we can use this command to select the subscription:

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId 5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxe29axxxx
```